# Ubuntu freezes when i copy or cut anything

Tags: freeze, clipboard, copy

When i copy or cut anything Ubuntu freezes for 1 or 2 seconds.
Under freeze i mean i can't do nothing except move mouse cursor. Can't change windows, can't move text cursor during freeze.

It also seems that this effect increases with time and resets when system was rebooted.
It does not depend what and how i copy. Ctrl+C, RMB->Copy, Ctrl+Ins has same effect.

This effect does not depend on program from which i copy. Copying text in terminal, gedit, Pycharm has same effect.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Edit 1:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        6.1G         21G        187M        4.0G         24G
Swap:          7.8G          0B        7.8G
```

Edit 2:

```
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 flowelcat flowelcat 4096 Mar 14  2019 .
drwx------ 3 flowelcat flowelcat 4096 Dec 11 19:56 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 flowelcat flowelcat 4096 Mar 14  2019 workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com

$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness 
vm.swappiness = 60
```

I have Nvidia GeForce 1080 8GB video card.
NVIDIA-SMI 430.50
Driver Version: 430.50
CUDA Version: 10.1

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Added free -h result

Comment: Edit your question again, and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: What video card/driver/driver version do you have?

Comment: Also show me `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`

Comment: @heynnema added new info

Comment: There's a new nvideo driver 441.66 released just yesterday. Try it and report back.

Comment: After trying the newer video driver, then go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CopyQ was causing this problem. I completely forgot that i installed it. After disabling copyq copying storing problem was solved.